# Kendo UI Grid - Inline Edit not change to database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui

I'm following the demo grid-edit inline 
It works but not change to database, it only change the list that popolated
what i have to do next

here the code

```
public static IList<Book> All()
    {
        IList<Book> result = (IList<Book>)HttpContext.Current.Session["Books"];

        if (result == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Books"] = result =
                (from book in new LibraryModel().Books
                 select new Book
                 {
                     PKiBookID=book.PKiBookID,
                     SBookName = book.SBookName,
                     SBookWriter= book.SBookWriter,
                     SDescription=book.SDescription,
                     BStatus=book.BStatus,
                     FKiBookType=book.FKiBookType

                 }).ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }
    public static Book One(Func<Book, bool> predicate)
    {
        return All().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    public static void Insert(Book book)
    {
        //book.PKiBookID = All().OrderByDescending(p => p.PKiBookID).First().PKiBookID + 1;
        All().Insert(0,book);
    }
    public static void Update(Book book)
    {
        Book target = One(p => p.PKiBookID == book.PKiBookID);
        if (target != null)
        {
            target.SBookName = book.SBookName;
            target.SBookWriter = book.SBookWriter;
            target.SDescription = book.SDescription;
            target.BStatus = book.BStatus;
            target.BookType = new LibraryModel().BookTypes.Single(s => s.PKiBookTypeID == book.FKiBookType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i use firebug and find the error is `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'LibraryProject.Book'`   any suggestion about searializing would help. Class book is generated with openaccess orm (database first) with asp.net MVC4. After that, it still insert to database but i've to rebuild entire solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is [quite well known](https://www.google.com/search?q=telerik%20mvc%20circular%20reference&aq=f&oq=telerik%20mvc%20circular%20reference&sugexp=chrome,mod=4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and there are many posts how to avoid it. It is also covered in the [Documentation](http://docs.kendoui.com/documentation/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/troubleshooting#a-circular-reference-was-detected-while-serializing-an-object-of-type).

Comment: i get this error after insert an record with reference key, the first time it load complete, what i can do now

Comment: i use a function to bind data for the dropdown in grid to choose the parent category    `private void populateBook()
        {
            ViewData["BookType"] = new LibraryModel().BookTypes
                .Select(e => new BookTypeViewModel
                {
                    PKiBookTypeID = e.PKiBookTypeID,
                    sBookTypeName = e.SBookTypeName
                });
        }` i call this function before Index `public ActionResult Index()
        {
            populateBook();
            return View();
        }`